# where to find a detailed demonstration on how to imitate the Token Kidnapping exploit by Argeniss?

Tags: exploit, iis, metasploit

I am looking for a way to do the Token Kidnapping’s Revenge exploit by Argeniss. (The vulnerability is explained in [here](http://www.argeniss.com/research/TokenKidnapping.pdf))

I am studying security (beginner) and I would like to imitate the attack to see exactly what it does and how it happens. I am using two VMs (victim VM is Win 2003 server, no security patches). But I am lacking enough information on how to prepare the Win 2003 server VM for the attack! And the steps (especially after running the handler exploit from the attacking VM)

I tried to follow the steps in the two resources I found about this kind of demonstration:

1) http://www.commonexploits.com/token-kidnapping-revenge/

2) [Playing with the MS09-012 Windows Local Exploit](http://carnal0wnage.attackresearch.com/2010/05/playing-with-ms09-012-windows-local.html)

But I feel there is a gab here. I installed IIS 6 and ASP.net on the victim VM but I am not sure if that was it (in terms of preps) and I am also messing some steps that I think the resources assume I should know already!

Any help about what I need to do to get this demo done? or is there another detailed how-to you can direct me to? I noticed other kinds of exploits are step-by-step detailed out there, but this one is not!